# Avoid an additional subselect in this UNION query?

Tags: sql, sap-iq

`shipping_customer` table:

```
+----+---------------+---------------------+
| id | business_name | billing_customer_id |
+----+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Soylent Corp  |                   3 |
|  2 | Initech       |                   4 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+
```

`billing_customer` table:

```
+----+--------------------+
| id |   business_name    |
+----+--------------------+
|  3 | Acme Corporation   |
|  4 | Globex Corporation |
+----+--------------------+
```

Ids are unique among the two tables. Wanted output is every customer (if shipping, select also the billing customer) with `id IN (1, 4)`:

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------+
|      id     |   business_name    |   type   |
+-------------+--------------------+----------+
|           1 | Soylent Corp       | shipping |
|           3 | Acme Corporation   | billing  | <- 1 has billing_customer = 3
|           4 | Globex Corporation | billing  |
+-------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to avoid the subselect?

```
SELECT id, business_name, 'shipping' AS type
FROM shipping_customer
WHERE id IN (1, 4)

UNION

SELECT id, business_name, 'billing' AS type
FROM billing_customer
WHERE 
    id IN (1, 4) OR
    id IN (SELECT billing_customer_id from shipping_customer WHERE id IN (1, 4))
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sybaseiq and an old version too.

Answer (score 1):

He asked without **subquery**.

Code:

```
SELECT id, business_name, 'shipping' AS type
FROM shipping_customer
WHERE id IN (1, 4)

UNION ALL

SELECT b.id AS [id], 
       b.business_name AS [business_name],
       'billing' AS [type]
FROM   shipping_customer s 
       JOIN billing_customer b 
              ON s.billing_customer_id = b.id 
WHERE  s.id IN ( 1, 4)
OR     b.id IN ( 1, 4)
```

Can you see if this is correct? I was not clear on what you meant by 'Wanted output is every customer'. This also might not be the most optimized way to do this.

Comment: This can return duplicates for the `billing` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION three sets:

1. Shipping Customer
2. Billing Customer
3. Shipping Customer Join to Billing Customer

   SELECT id, business_name, 'shipping' AS type
   FROM shipping_customer
   WHERE id IN (1, 4)
   UNION
   SELECT id, business_name, 'billing' AS type
   FROM billing_customer
   WHERE 
       id IN (1, 4)
   UNION
   SELECT sc.billing_customer_id, 
      bc.business_name, 'billing via shipping' as type
   FROM shipping_customer sc INNER JOIN 
     billing_customer bc on sc.billing_customer_id = bc.id
   WHERE sc.billing_customer_id IN (1, 4)

Query in the question is a good explicit way to do it, the only thing I would replace IN with EXISTS:

```
SELECT id, business_name, 'shipping' AS type
FROM shipping_customer
WHERE id IN (1, 4)
UNION
SELECT id, business_name, 'billing' AS type
FROM billing_customer bc
WHERE 
    id IN (1, 4) OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shipping_customer 
            WHERE bc.id = billing_customer_id AND id IN (1, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT IIF(customerType = 'sName', scId, bcId) AS id,
       customer,
       IIF (customerType = 'sName', 'shipping', 'billing') AS type
FROM (
   SELECT sc.id AS scId, bc.id AS bcId, 
          sc.business_name AS sName, bc.business_name AS bName
   FROM shipping_customer AS sc
   INNER JOIN billing_customer AS bc ON sc.billing_customer_id = bc.id
) src
UNPIVOT (
   customer FOR customerType IN  (sName, bName)
) unpvt      
WHERE (customerType = 'sName' AND (scId IN (1,4))) 
      OR ((customerType = 'bName') AND ((scId IN (1,4)) OR (bcId IN (1,4))))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/463b6/2)